# postgresql 9.* - user cannot SELECT from VIEW inside a SCHEMA as DEFAULT PRIVILEGE

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema

hope you can help me.

I have 3 users

- First is me, the db admin. I run the GRANT queries, I can do anything. (name doesn't matter now)
- Second is the data manager user. = **manager_u**
- Third is the data viewer user. = **viewer_u**

**The "data viewer" should read from views created by "data manager", without managing privileges afterwards**
For that reason I create a schema, owned by manager, that should be full open to the viewer.

The problem/actual situation is (after running my following code) this.

**When manager_u create a named view, viewer_u cannot SELECT from it.**

If I run this, AFTER the creation:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u TO viewer_u;
```

he can read. Everything works.
But I like that he can read any further views without managing his privileges.
I tried with that, with no success:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE viewer_u IN SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO viewer_u;
```

Here, the complete code:

```
--
-- QUERIES as db admin
-- 

CREATE ROLE manager_u LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;
CREATE ROLE viewer_u LOGIN NOSUPERUSER INHERIT NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOREPLICATION;


ALTER ROLE manager_u WITH PASSWORD 'yyy';
ALTER ROLE viewer_u WITH PASSWORD 'xxx';


GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO manager_u;
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE mydb TO viewer_u;


---
---                     schema
---
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS views_for_viewer_u;

ALTER SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u OWNER TO manager_u;

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u TO manager_u;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u TO manager_u;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE manager_u IN SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO manager_u;

---
---   privileges on views_for_viewer_u schema
---   I think the problem is here but I'm going crazy
---   I beg help
---

GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u TO viewer_u;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u TO viewer_u;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE viewer_u IN SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO viewer_u;



--
-- QUERIES as data manager:  manager_u
--

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW views_for_viewer_u.proxy_table
    AS SELECT * FROM another_schema.a_table;


--
-- QUERIES as viewer:  viewer_u
--

SELECT * FROM views_for_viewer_u.proxy_table; -- this is what is not working
--
--
-- thanks to anyone can give an hint
--
--
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` command. It should be

`ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE manager_u ...`

This way, the views created by `manager_u` will get the permission granted.

Comment: Hello,
first, thanks for your kind reply.
I tried with the advice you gave (and I corrected the question after your suggestion), but didn't worked.

The main problem is the viewer privileges, not the manager privileges.
I think that after giving the ownership (I do) of the schema to the manager, his privileges are already enough.

How can I give SELECT privileges (only) to a viewer for future VIEW(s) inside a schema? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Then you actually did something different from what you said, because that would definitely be the right thing. Check the default privileges with `\ddp` in `psql`.

Answer (score 0):

Default privileges are given at the creation moment based on the creator role.

```
FOR ROLE xxx
```

stands for that.

the problem is here: xxx should be who will make the creation query... 
if "FOR ROLE xxx" is omitted, "FOR ROLE actual_role" will be implicit: db admin, in my case.

So I had to do that.

because manager_u is who will create the tables...

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u TO viewer_u;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u TO viewer_u;
--- here
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE manager_u IN SCHEMA views_for_viewer_u GRANT 
SELECT ON TABLES TO viewer_u;
```